# input boxes value of table should not be greater then input box outside of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I have developed a form where input boxes value of table should not be greater then input box outside of table.

```html
<form>
 <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="label1 col-md-4">Total number of sanctioned seats
                               <span class="required"> * </span>
                              </label>
         <div class="col-md-7">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sanctionedSeatsSummary">
                              </div>
        </div>
        
                                                <table  class="eduleveles table table-bordered table-hover">
         
    <thead> 
        <th></th>
        <th>Faculty</th>
  <th>Enter sanctioned seats</th>
        
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Check" class="cbxenable">
            </td>
            <td>
               
            </td>
   <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control seats" name="seats">
            </td>
 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Check" class="cbxenable">
            </td>
            <td>
               
            </td>
   <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control seats" name="seats">
            </td>
 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Check" class="cbxenable">
            </td>
            <td>
               
            </td>
   <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control seats" name="seats">
            </td>
 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

in above jsfiddle all ENTER SANCTIONED SEATS sum will not be greater then "Enter total number of sanctioned seats" in onchange.

Comment: you can use onkeyup event of jquery to validate your result.What happen when i change total number after filling all sanctioned seats?

Comment: can you help me some working fiddle ?

Comment: yup I am creating fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use jquery keyup event as I mentioned in fiddle.

Please check this fiddle

Here I just made textbox value blank if sum of three sanctioned seats are greater than total.

Also i have cleare 3 textbox if you chane total textbox

`Open this link` : https://jsfiddle.net/5y6na3wr/7/

Comment: can we have a warning message if we exceed total sanctioned seats?

Comment: yes we can. which type of warning you want?I updated latest fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".seats").on('keyup',function(){
     var total = parseInt(0) ;
     $( ".seats" ).each(function( index ) {
         if($(this).val()){
          total = total + parseInt($(this).val());
            } 
  });
  if(total > $("#sanctionedSeatsSummary").val()){
   alert("total sanctioned Seats are greater then given sanctioned Seats");
  }
        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="label1 col-md-4">Total number of sanctioned seats
  <span class="required"> * </span>
  </label>
  <div class="col-md-7">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sanctionedSeatsSummary">
  </div>
 </div>

<table  class="eduleveles table table-bordered table-hover">
 <thead> 
  <th></th>
  <th>Faculty</th>
  <th>Enter sanctioned seats</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="checkbox" name="Check" class="cbxenable">
  </td>
  <td>
  </td>
  <td>
   <input type="text" class="form-control seats" name="seats">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="checkbox" name="Check" class="cbxenable">
  </td>
  <td>
  </td>
  <td>
   <input type="text" class="form-control seats" name="seats">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="checkbox" name="Check" class="cbxenable">
  </td>
  <td>
  </td>
  <td>
   <input type="text" class="form-control seats" name="seats">
  </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

check below snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var ttl, val;
  
  $("input[name=seats]").on('keyup', function(){
    val = 0;
    
    $("input[name=seats]").each(function(){
      if(parseInt($(this).val().trim()) > 0)
      val += parseInt($(this).val().trim());
    });
    
    ttl = parseInt($("#sanctionedSeatsSummary").val().trim());

    if(val > ttl)
      alert("your alert");
    
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
 <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="label1 col-md-4">Total number of sanctioned seats
                               <span class="required"> * </span>
                              </label>
         <div class="col-md-7">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sanctionedSeatsSummary">
                              </div>
        </div>
        
                                                <table  class="eduleveles table table-bordered table-hover">
         
    <thead> 
        <th></th>
        <th>Faculty</th>
  <th>Enter sanctioned seats</th>
        
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Check" class="cbxenable">
            </td>
            <td>
               
            </td>
   <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control seats" name="seats">
            </td>
 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Check" class="cbxenable">
            </td>
            <td>
               
            </td>
   <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control seats" name="seats">
            </td>
 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Check" class="cbxenable">
            </td>
            <td>
               
            </td>
   <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control seats" name="seats">
            </td>
 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```